# Adding Jquery to a bundle with webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to bundle my script with jQuery, which is required for it to work. It is a snippet that other webmasters must insert into their website, so I don't want it to interfere with whatever jQuery they might be running.

I've followed the instructions as follows:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
});
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  entry: "./clickscape.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
    filename: 'clickscape-bundle.js'
  }
});
```

I also have the following package.json:

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch-stdin --progress --color"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

It builds without errors, but jQuery isn't available for my final script. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `jquery` to the plugins array in `webpack.config.js` as shown below.

This will enable webpack to inject jquery object globally into all js files in the dependency graph

```
./webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports={
    entry:{
        index : "./src/index.js"
    },
    output :{
        filename : "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            divine:'jquery'
        })
    ]
}
```

Generate js bundle with below instruction and verify the result.
Utility functions provided by jquery can be accessed using either `$` or `jQuery` or `divine`.
You can choose to use any one of them or all of them.

```
./src/index.js

console.log("jquery object ",jQuery);
console.log("jquery $ ",$);
console.log("jquery divine ",divine)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I have one further question. What's the best way to call the functions from an HTML page with my bundle attached? So for example, if I insert it into my page with `<script src="http://localhost:4000/js/clickscape-bundle.js"></script>`, subsequent `<script>` tags don't have access to the functions inside. It's necessary to call functions outside as I need to include a userid as part of the call.

Comment: @cjm2671 you need to access a JS function that is present inside your bundle from your html page, is it?

Comment: @cjm2671 there is one simple way and there is one good way . i will mention the simple way here. you can do this in any of the pages that's in your dependency graph. Attach the function that you would like to trigger from html page to the window object , var myfunc = function(){
    console.log("in my func");
};
window.myfunc = myfunc; ...now in htmlfile you can invoke this function just like that myfunc(......)

Comment: @cjm2671 is this one ok for you?

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you! Out of curiosity, what was the 'good' way?

Comment: @cjm2671 using closure is the good way, because you wouldn't attach anything to the window object .

Comment: @cjm2671 would you need that solution too?

Comment: @cjm2671 nice :)

Comment: @cjm2671 i would like to correct my statement about using closure. even when we use closure, we will need to attach minimum of one object(this could be maximum too) to window object to make it work.

Comment: @cjm2671 i think might be wrong about using closure to expose functions. as of now, attaching to window object seems to be the only simple and good way. ignore closure for this scenario.